# how to write query for A(table) union B(table) intersect C(table) in mysql

Tags: mysql

Iam try to do this

```
select Barcode from ITList union select Barcode from Equipment_list
intersect select Barcode from Scanneditem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this:

```
SELECT a.Barcode FROM Scanneditem AS a
JOIN (SELECT Barcode FROM ITList UNION SELECT Barcode FROM Equipment_list) AS b
ON a.Barcode=b.Barcode;
```

Comment: this query showing this error ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'Barcode' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: you can use either a.barcode or b.barcode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Exists for this

```
Select * from (select Barcode from ITList union select Barcode from   Equipment_list) as t 
where exists (select Barcode from Scanneditem where Scanneditem.Barcode = t.Barcode)
```

Comment: this query showing error     "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select Barcode from Scanneditem where Scanneditem.Barcode = t.Barcode)' at line 1"

Comment: @varadharajanp.rRajan If you had a problem with this answer, why did you accept it? Please only accept answers that work for you.

Comment: iam new to stackoverflow so unfortunately i did

Comment: SQL error due to spelling mistake. i have edited.

Answer (score -1):

Although there is no INTERSECT operator in MySQL, you can easily simulate this type of query using either the IN clause or the EXISTS clause, depending on the complexity of the INTERSECT query.

Please try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Barcode FROM ITList UNION SELECT Barcode FROM Equipment_list) AS allbarcode 
WHERE allbarcode.Barcode IN (SELECT Barcode FROM Scanneditem)
```

You can also check Naveen Goyal sql with EXISTS clause(Below reply).

Comment: this is print what i have in scanneditem class but  i want except this barcode from ITList and Equipmetlist table

Comment: mysql> select Barcode from scanneditem;
+---------+
| Barcode |
+---------+
| HCL78   |
| ACCE78  |
+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select Barcode from ITList union select Barcode from Equipment_List;
+-----------+
| Barcode   |
+-----------+
| HCL78     |
| ACCE78    |
| ERTUYS    |
| WWERT     |
| IOWREUIR  |
| DELL78    |
| IOERP     |
| 23423uiuf |
+-----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: i want except that scanned item class data.

Comment: Do you want data from ITList and Equipmetlist table that are not present in scanneditem table?

Comment: yes correct i want like that

Comment: Simply replace IN clause With NOT IN. So here is your modified query.


SELECT * FROM (SELECT Barcode FROM ITList UNION SELECT Barcode FROM Equipment_list) AS allbarcode 
WHERE allbarcode.Barcode NOT IN (SELECT Barcode FROM Scanneditem)

Comment: @varadharajanp.rRajan. Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: one more thing i want ... After getting this data i want to split these data on the specific table in ITList and Equipment List